# Starting Rebar3 project for development with console and code updating

Tags: emacs, erlang, rebar

I created a project with Rebar3 like this

```
rebar new release app1
```

I then compiled it:

```
rebar3 compile
```

Now the question is, with Rebar3, how do I start a project in development mode?

My requirements are:

1. That it would be started as an Erlang node
2. To make it start with the dependencies and initialize the application
3. To start with an interactive shell
4. The ability to to compile on the fly from Emacs

Or can I only start a Rebar3 shell by hand and set the cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start the project you need to build release first. Rebar3 delegates this to relx tool. [See here](http://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases). As you have built release you are able to run it just as `./_build/default/bin/node_name`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I did compile my project and run them as 
**pacman@proton:~/git/e/hronograf$ ./_build/default/rel/hronograf/bin/hronograf console** , then I run my emacs and conect my erlang-shell to this node successefuly. One problem, I can not compile my code as C-c C-k. erlang-shell give me the next message ** exception error: undefined function compile:file/2
     in function  c:c/2 (c.erl, line 89)**